# A trigger to create populate a table based on other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, candlestick-chart

Ok, since it seems that my last two questions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744527/how-to-use-correctly-if-statement-postgresql) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759287/syntax-error-near-or-at-case-postgresql)) only lead to confussion, I will try to explain the FULL problem here, so it might be a long post.

I'm trying to create a database for a trading system. The database has 2 main tables. One is table "Ticks" and the other is "Candles". As shown in the figure, each table has its own attributes.[image: Attributes of table ticks and candles].

Candles, bars or ohlc are the same thing.

The way a candle is seen in a chart is like this:

[image: Bearish and bullish candles]

Candles are just a way to representate aggregated data, nothing more.

There are many ways to aggregate ticks in order to create one candle. In this post, I'm asking for a particular way that is creating one candle every 500 ticks. So, if the `ticks` table has 1000 ticks, I can create only 2 candles. If it has 500 ticks, I can create 1 candle. If it has 5000 ticks, I can create 10 candles. If there are 5001 ticks I still have only 10 candles, because I'm missing the other 499 ticks in order to create the 11th candle.

Actually, I'm storing all the ticks using a python script and creating (and therefore, inserting in the `candles` table) candles with another python script. **This is a real time process**.

Both scripts run in a `while True:` loop. No, I can't (read shouldn't) stop the scripts because the market is opened 24 hours - 5 days a week.

What I'm trying to do is to get rid of the python script that creates and stores the candles in the `candles` table. Why? Because I think that it will improve performance. Instead of doing multiple queries to know the amount of ticks that are available to create a new candle, I think that a trigger could handle it in a more efficient way **(please, if I'm mistaken correct me)**.

I don't know how to actually solve it, but what I'm trying is to do this (thanks to @GordonLinoff for helping me in previous questions):

```
do $$

begin
with total_ticks as (
    select count(*) c from (
    select *  from eurusd_tick2 eurusd where date > 
        (SELECT date from eurusd_ohlc order by date desc limit 1) 
        order by date asc) totals),
        ticks_for_candles as(
        select * from eurusd_tick2 eurusd where date > 
        (SELECT date from eurusd_ohlc order by date desc limit 1) 
        order by date asc
        ), candles as(
       select max(date) as date,
       max(bid) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 1) as open,
       max(bid) as high,
       min(bid) as low,
       max(bid) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 500-1) as close,
       max(ask) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 500-1) as ask

        from (
            select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
              from (select * from ticks_for_candles) t) as a

        group by floor((seqnum - 1) /500)
        having count(*) = 500
        )


case 500<(select * from total_ticks)
when true then

        return select * from candles
    end;
end $$;
```

Using this, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"
LINE 33: case 500<(select * from total_ticks)
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 945
```

As you can see, there is no `select` after the CETs. If I put:

```
select case 500<(select * from total_ticks)
    when true then

            return select * from candles
        end;
    end $$;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 31:   (select * from candles)
           ^
QUERY:  with total_ticks as (
    select count(*) c from (
    select *  from eurusd_tick2 eurusd where date > 
        (SELECT date from eurusd_ohlc order by date desc limit 1) 
        order by date asc) totals),
        ticks_for_candles as(
        select * from eurusd_tick2 eurusd where date > 
        (SELECT date from eurusd_ohlc order by date desc limit 1) 
        order by date asc
        ), candles as(
       select max(date) as date,
       max(bid) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 1) as open,
       max(bid) as high,
       min(bid) as low,
       max(bid) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 500-1) as close,
       max(ask) filter (where mod(seqnum, 500) = 500-1) as ask

        from (
            select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
              from (select * from ticks_for_candles) t) as a

        group by floor((seqnum - 1) /500)
        having count(*) = 500
        )


select case 1000>(select * from total_ticks)
when true then

        (select * from candles)
    end
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

So honestly, I don't know how to do it correctly. It doesn't has to be with the actual code I provide here, but the desired output looks as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          date            |    open   |   high   |    low  |   close  |    ask   |
|2020-05-01 20:39:27.603452|    1.0976 |  1.09766 | 1.09732 | 1.09762  |  1.09776 |
```

This would be the output when there is enough ticks to create only 1 candle. If there is enough to create two of them, then there should be 2 rows.

So, at the end of the day, what I have in mind is that the trigger should check constantly if there is enough data to create a candle and if it is, then create it.

- Is this a good idea or I should stick to the python script?
- Can this be achieved with my approach?
- What I'm doing wrong?
- What should I do and how should I manage this situation?

I really hope that the question now is complete and there is no missing information.
All comments and advices are appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Since this is a real time process, in one second there could be 499 ticks in the database and in the next second there could be 503 ticks. This means that 4 ticks arrived in 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a database guy, my approach would be to use triggers in the database.

Create a third table `candle_in_the_making` that contains the data from the ticks that have not yet been aggregated to a `candles` entry.

Create an `INSERT` trigger on the `ticks` table (doesn't matter if `BEFORE` or `AFTER`) that does the following:

- For every tick inserted, add a row to `candle_in_the_making`.
- If the row count reaches 500, compute and insert a new `candles` row and `TRUNCATE candle_in_the_making`.

This is simple if `ticks` are inserted only in a single thread.

If `ticks` are inserted concurrently, you have to find a way to prevent two threads from inserting the 500th tick in `candle_in_the_making` at the same time (so that you end up with 501 entries). I can think of two ways to do that in the database:

1. Have an extra table `c_i_m_count` that contains only a single number, which is the number of rows in `candle_in_the_making`. Before you insert into `candle_in_the_making`, you run the atomic

   ```
   UPDATE c_i_m_count SET counter = counter + 1 RETURNING counter;
   ```

   This locks the row, so that any two `INSERT`s into `counter_in_the_making` are effectively serialized.
2. Use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) to serialize the inserting threads. In particular, a *transaction level exclusive lock* as taken by `pg_advisory_xact_lock` would be indicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @LaurenzAlbe. The ticks can arrive in a random number per second. That means that I could, for example, have 499 ticks and in the next second I could have 502 ticks. That's why I start counting the number of ticks based on the last date of the candles, because the date used corresponds to the close timestamp

Comment: Then your question is unclear. My answer assumes a "first come, first served" strategy for the ticks. If you have a different, more complicated requirement, you should state that in your question.

Comment: Just to specify, when I said that first I had 499 ticks and in the next second I could have 502 ticks, that means that in 1 second 3 ticks arrived.

Comment: Yes, but you don't specify which of these three ticks should complete the candle. If it could be any of them, my answer should be good.

Comment: Hmmm the tick that completes the candle is the 500th tick. How do you handle the tick 501th and 502th? This is a time series problem

Comment: As I said in my answer: if the ticks come sequentially in a single connection, there is an implicit order. In the case of concurrent inserts, the two synchronization methods I proposed will take care that one of the ticks completes the candle, and the remaining two will start a new one.